# Ursina destroy is not available

Tags: python, game-engine, ursina

I implemented the game over message window in Ursina, but the screen does not switch when the game ends

- "After receiving feedback that 'Looks like you're instantiating a new GameOverScene every frame', I made further modifications."

```
class StartGame1(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.game_over = False
        self.player = Entity(model='sphere', color=color.hex('#cf522d'), position=(0, 3, 0), scale=(5, 5, 5), collider='box')

        camera.z = -50
        camera.add_script(SmoothFollow(target=self.player, offset=(0, 5, -30)))

        self.length = 1000  # 각 조각의 길이
        self.num_segments = 11  # 총 조각의 개수
        self.bg_music = Audio('stage1.mp3', loop=True)
        self.bg_music.play()
        self.while_music = Audio('while.mp3', loop=False, autoplay=False)

        for i in range(self.num_segments):
            road = Entity(model='plane', scale=(40, 10, self.length), color=color.black, z=i*self.length)
            if i == self.num_segments - 1:
                self.finish_line = Entity(model='cube', scale=(50, 10, 10), color=color.red, z=self.length * (self.num_segments - 1) - 10)

        self.rows = [-15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15]
        self.score_board = Text(text=str(0), scale=5, x=-0.85, y=0.45)
        self.speed = 200

        for i in range(700, int(self.finish_line.z), 100):
            enemy = Entity(model='cube', collider='box', position=(random.choice(self.rows), 6, i), color=color.random_color())
            enemy.scale = (10, 10, 10)

        self.sky = Sky()

    
    def update(self):
        self.speed = 200
        self.player.z += time.dt * self.speed
        self.player.rotation_x += time.dt * 50
        score_val = self.player.z / 10
        score = int(score_val)

        if self.game_over:  # 게임 오버 상태면 update 함수의 로직을 실행하지 않습니다.
            return
        
        if held_keys['d']:
            self.player.x += time.dt * 25
            self.player.rotation_z += time.dt * 100
            self.while_music.play()
        if held_keys['a']:
            self.player.x -= time.dt * 25
            self.player.rotation_z -= time.dt * 100
            self.while_music.play()

        if self.player.intersects().hit:
            print("Fail", "Score:", score)
            GameOverScene(score, self)
            self.game_over = True

        if score >= 1000:
            print("Success", "Score:", score)
            GameOverScene(score,self)
            self.game_over = True

        self.score_board.text = str(score)
```

```
class GameOverScene(Entity):
    def __init__(self, score, start_game_instance):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.start_game_instance = start_game_instance  

        
      
        self.message = Text("Game Over", scale=2, color=color.red, y=0.2)
        
        
        self.score_display = Text(f"Score: {score}", scale=1.5, y=-0.1)
        
        self.back_button = Button(text='Back to Main Menu', scale=0.1,color=color.red,y=0,z=0)
        self.back_button.on_click = self.back_to_main
        
    def back_to_main(self):
        print("back to main menu")
        
        destroy(self.start_game_instance)
        MainScene()
```

I tried to create a Game Over scene class and transition to the Game Over scene class when the player touches an enemy. However, when a failure occurs, only the message, text, and button are created, but I cannot transition to the main scene class when clicking the button (initially used parent=self for the button).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rASAG.png)
From the picture, you can see that when the button is clicked, 'back to main menu' is displayed

+"I added the game_over attribute to the StartGame1 class and modified the code to check the game_over status before checking the game over conditions in the update method.

So, when the player collides with an enemy, the button and text are displayed, and clicking the button triggers the print("Back button was clicked!"). However, both self.disable() and self.main_scene = MainScene() seem to not be working.

```
def on_back_click(self):
print('Back button was clicked!')
self.disable(self)
self.main_scene = MainScene()
```

full code

```
from ursina import *

import random
import time



app = Ursina()
def Exit():
    app.quit()



class MainScene(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button1 = Button(text='Button 1', parent=self, x=0, y=2)
        self.button1.on_click = self.on_button1_click

        self.button2 = Button(text='Button 2', parent=self, x=0, y=0.5)
        self.button2.on_click = self.on_button2_click

        self.button3 = Button(text='Button 3', parent=self, x=0, y=-2)
        self.button3.on_click = self.on_button3_click

    def on_button1_click(self):
        print('Button 1 was clicked!')
        # Transition to StageScene
        destroy(self)  # Destroy the current MainScene
        self.stage_scene = StageScene()  # Create the StageScene

    def on_button2_click(self):
        print('Button 2 was clicked!')
        destroy(self)
        self.InventoryScene = InventoryScene()
            
    def on_button3_click(self):
        print('Button 3 was clicked!')
        application.quit()

class StartGame1(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.game_over = False
        self.player = Entity(model='sphere', color=color.hex('#cf522d'), position=(0, 3, 0), scale=(5, 5, 5), collider='box')

        camera.z = -50
        camera.add_script(SmoothFollow(target=self.player, offset=(0, 5, -30)))

        self.length = 1000  # 각 조각의 길이
        self.num_segments = 11  # 총 조각의 개수
        self.bg_music = Audio('stage1.mp3', loop=True)
        self.bg_music.play()
        self.while_music = Audio('while.mp3', loop=False, autoplay=False)

        for i in range(self.num_segments):
            road = Entity(model='plane', scale=(40, 10, self.length), color=color.black, z=i*self.length)
            if i == self.num_segments - 1:
                self.finish_line = Entity(model='cube', scale=(50, 10, 10), color=color.red, z=self.length * (self.num_segments - 1) - 10)

        self.rows = [-15, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 15]
        self.score_board = Text(text=str(0), scale=5, x=-0.85, y=0.45)
        self.speed = 200

        for i in range(700, int(self.finish_line.z), 100):
            enemy = Entity(model='cube', collider='box', position=(random.choice(self.rows), 6, i), color=color.random_color())
            enemy.scale = (10, 10, 10)

        self.sky = Sky()

    
    def update(self):
        self.speed = 200
        self.player.z += time.dt * self.speed
        self.player.rotation_x += time.dt * 50
        score_val = self.player.z / 10
        score = int(score_val)

        if self.game_over:  # 게임 오버 상태면 update 함수의 로직을 실행하지 않습니다.
            return
        
        if held_keys['d']:
            self.player.x += time.dt * 25
            self.player.rotation_z += time.dt * 100
            self.while_music.play()
        if held_keys['a']:
            self.player.x -= time.dt * 25
            self.player.rotation_z -= time.dt * 100
            self.while_music.play()

        if self.player.intersects().hit:
            print("Fail", "Score:", score)
            GameOverScene(score, self)
            self.game_over = True

        if score >= 1000:
            print("Success", "Score:", score)
            GameOverScene(score,self)
            self.game_over = True

        self.score_board.text = str(score)


class GameOverScene(Entity):
    def __init__(self, score, start_game_instance):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.start_game_instance = start_game_instance  

        
        # 게임 오버 메시지
        self.message = Text("Game Over", scale=2, color=color.red, y=0.2)
        
        # 플레이어의 최종 점수 표시
        self.score_display = Text(f"Score: {score}", scale=1.5, y=-0.1)
        
        # 메인 메뉴로 돌아가는 버튼
        self.back_button = Button(text='Back to Main Menu', scale=0.1,color=color.red,y=0,z=0)
        self.back_button.on_click = self.back_to_main
        
    def back_to_main(self):
        print("back to main menu")
        
        destroy(self.start_game_instance)
        MainScene()    # 메인 화면으로 돌아감       



class StageScene(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.back_button = Button(text='Back', parent=self, x=0, y=0)
        self.back_button.on_click = self.on_back_click
        
        self.go_button1 = Button(icon='land.png',scale=(2,4,6), color=color.clear, parent=self, x=0, y=1)
        self.go_button1.on_click = self.on_go1_click
        
        self.go_button2 = Button(text='go2',parent=self, x=0, y=3)
        self.go_button2.on_click = self.on_go2_click        
        
        self.go_button3 = Button(text='go3',parent=self, x=0, y=-2) 
        self.go_button3.on_click = self.on_go3_click
    
    def on_back_click(self):
        print('Back button was clicked!')
        # Transition back to MainScene
        self.disable(self)  # Destroy the current StageScene
        self.main_scene = MainScene()  # Create the MainScene

    def on_go1_click(self):
        print('go button was clicked!')

        self.start_game = StartGame1()  # Start the game
        destroy(self)  # Destroy the current StageScene

    def on_go2_click(self):
        print('go2 button was clicked!')
        
    def on_go3_click(self):
        print('go3 button was clicked!')
    
class InventoryScene(Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.back_button = Button(text='Back', parent=self, x=0,y=0)
        self.back_button.on_click = self.on_back_click
        
    def on_back_click(self):
        print('Back button was clicked!')
        destroy(self)
        self.main_scene = MainScene()


main_scene = MainScene()
app.run()
```

Comment: Looks like you're instantiating a new GameOverScene every frame